# Make uniform colored Bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I need a Bitmap that only red or any other color. Can I use the `CreateBitmap()` and if so how??

```
Bitmap b= Bitmap.createBitmap //WHAT DO I NEED HERE?
```

Any ideas?

Comment: (WHAT DO I NEED HERE)You need to be specify more explanation... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in an inefficent way:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        bitmap.setPixel(i, j, Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0));
     }
 }
```

for a full red bitmap

Comment: Ok thanks works well though. I just downloaded colored PNGs and scaled those as a workaround..